# Appending {{ jinja }}

Tags: jquery, macros, flask, append, jinja2

I'm creating a form in which user can add an extra field or two... I'm using jQuery for interaction and Flask for templating and it looks like this:

```
<div id="edu_extension"></div>
<a id="add_edu" class="add_line">Add College or University</a>
<script>
   $( document ).ready(function() {
   $(".add_line").mouseup(function(){
        $("#edu_extension").append("
             {{ forms.year('', form_consultant_errors.year, 'pick a year','college1-yearpicker')}}
        ");
   });
   })   
</script>
```

but unfortunately Jinja code breaks the script causing footer to stick in the middle of the page and rendering the code after the code that has to be appended:

```
"); });})
```

So I thought, is there a function like CDATA in xml, that would handle the code without parsing it?

Comment: You mean you don't want the `{{ forms.year(....)}}` part to be interpreted by Jinja?

Comment: @MartijnPieters exactly the  opposite: I want it to be interpreted by Jinja once it is appended but I don't want jQuery trying to interpret   it as javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tojson|safe` to interpolate Jinja results into Javascript:

```
$("#edu_extension").append(
     {{ forms.year('', form_consultant_errors.year, 'pick a year','college1-yearpicker')|tojson|safe }}
);
```

This produces a JavaScript-quoted value for you.

Comment: This is great but i was planing to change dynamically ids:

        "{{ forms.year('', form_consultant_errors.year, 'pick a year','college"+i+"-yearpicker')|tojson|safe }}

any idea how to manage that?

Comment: And where is `i` going to come from?

Comment: declared in script

        var i=1;

and increased before each appending: i++

Comment: But that's in JavaScript; executed on the client side. Jinja templates are executed on the server side, before being sent to the client. You cannot mix both.

Comment: Either you need to generate a *list* of form widgets on the server side, or you need to parse the generated HTML on the client side in JavaScript and replace the `college1-yearpicker` string each iteration.

Comment: I was afraid something like that would happen... I'm already using this structure to generate html content (headlines and ids). Any idea how to solve this problem? And thank you for all your help!